# Advanced grouping and sorting in outlook sort groups by received date

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I am trying to reproduce a outlook setup I had a number of years ago 10+ at a previous place of work.

I had my emails grouped by From and then sorted by received date this I can reproduce.

however the new groups were sorted by revived date so rather than the groups being in alphabetical order based on sender name they were sorted by last email received.  This allowed for me to have a collapsed group for each person that had sent me an email and these groups would be ordered by last email received.

Is something like this still possible?

Thanks

Comment: You may achieve this via View > View Settings > Group By...

Comment: hi @Aidan so whenever I have attempted this via the View settings and Group by the best I can arrive at is grouped by user and I can sort within the group based on received.  but I am attempting to sort the groups themselves so the last email in is always the top group